# rails 3.1.3 app on Heroku doesn't find (or precompile) vendor/assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

My rails 3.1 app runs fine locally, but when I run it on Heroku the logs show Rails is not finding javascripts inside the `vendors/assets/javascripts` directory even though browsing them manually works.

I am using the plupload-rails3 gem, and the gem's javascripts are not loading on Heroku, but do load fine on my local dev machine.

In my assets/javascripts/application.js I have:

```
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/plupload-rails3
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/plupload-rails3
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/images/plupload-rails3
```

When I run my app on Heroku the logs show Rails trying to load and failing with each of the plupload javascripts, with a token identifier:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/plupload-rails3/plupload/js/plupload.full-f4741a878138cea127e6b38b6a08cf12.js"):

So the plupload widget does not display on the page on Heroku (but does when I run locally).

However, if I manually browse that location (without the ID token):

http://MYAPPNAME.herokuapp.com/assets/plupload-rails3/plupload/js/plupload.full.js
I do see the file.

I have also tried precompiling the assets locally, then pushing to Heroku, with same result.

So something in my app is broken with Rails on Heroku accessing the vendor/assets pipeline.

(I do have `config.assets.compile = true` in my production.rb file. The original setting of false caused the app to crash when it failed to find the precompiled assets, at least now it doesn't crash, but it ignores the javascript widget.)

Answer (score 0):

Application.js is a manifest file for javascript, you don't want to include images or css in it.
vendor/assets/javascripts should already be in the path it is searching so just include:

```
//= require_tree ./plupload-rails3
```

Edit:
you can do similar to include the css in application.css, images do not need to be included in a manifest.

Check out the Rails Guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html and Ryan Bates Railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline for more info.

Edit2: just looked through the gem, did you run

```
bundle exec rake plupload_rails3:install_assets
```

To install the assets? If not, run that, then try the code above.

Comment: when I try that I get the error `ActionView::Template::Error (require_tree argument must be a directory (in /Users/MYNAME/myapps/APPNAME/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:13))`

Comment: I presumed it was from the post. Try //= require plupload-rails3

Comment: yes, I did run the rake task. and for the require_tree it has to be a relative path (relative to where application.js is), so the ../../../ is apparently necessary. So the problem persists... the assets in vendor/assets in my app are not accessible to Rails when running on Heroku